# remove empty string from array vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, split

I am trying to get each sentence from my `rtextbox` into an array. However, when I use `.split` method, it gives me empty spaces as part of the array.

How can I either remove the empty ones or not have them come into the array in the first place?

```
Dim senArray() = RTextBox.Text.Split(New String() {"."}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of the output? Do you have actual entries that are blank, or do you have spaces at the the start of some sentences?

Comment: when i try linq Where expression, it gives me the following error: Variable cannot be initialized with non-array type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of String)'

Comment: try adding `.ToArray()` after your `Where` expression

Comment: @valverij Missed that when I added my answer - Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [linq `Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) expression to remove the whitespace entries:

```
Dim senArray() = RTextBox.Text.Split(
                     New String() {"."}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
                 ).Where(
                     Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(s)
                 ).ToArray()
```

Comment: Where is not a member of System.array :(

Comment: @johnktejik Indeed - it's an extension method made available via `System.Linq` - you'd need to include that using to make it available.